# How to dinamicly delete current <div> in for loop with jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need delete dinamicly div in my for loop, I try do that with jquery but it delete only "Delete" button but I need delete button and in div textbox and checkbox
this is my code

```
<div class="editorRow">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.AnswerList.Count; i++)
            {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AnswerList[i].Description)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.AnswerList[i].IS_Right, new { id = '1'})

                <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
             <script type="text/javascript">
                    $("a.deleteRow").click( function () {
                        $(this).click(".editorRow").remove();
                     return false;
                   });
             </script>
            }

    </div>
```

Comment: take your script out of your loop block, you are duplicating unnecessarily code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$("a.deleteRow").click( function () {
  $(this).closest('.editorRow').remove();
  return false;
});
```

Note you are giving all your checkboxes the same `id` attribute (that's invalid html)

Comment: That's what you asked for!

Comment: I fix it with adding new div in for loop

Comment: Note you should also remove the script from the loop and just place it once at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$("a.deleteRow").click( function () {
  $(this).parent('.editorRow').remove();
  return false;
});
```